# Datetime in bytes

Tags: python, datetime, hex, byte

I am trying to decode datetime from byte form. I tried various methods (seconds, minutes, hours form 1-1-1970, minutes form 1-1-1 etc). I also tried mysql encoding (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html) with no effect either.
Please help me find the datetime save key.

```
bf aa b8 c3 e5 2f
d7 be ba c3 e5 2f
80 a0 c0 c3 e5 2f
a7 fc bf c3 e5 2f
ae fd f2 c3 e5 2f
9e dd fa c3 e5 2f
c7 ce fa c3 e5 2f
b9 f5 82 c4 e5 2f
f8 95 f2 c3 e5 2f
```

Everything is around 01/14/2022 12:00

Comment: It's VARINT encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each value is a timestamp encoded into [VARINT](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints). Long time ago I've made next functions to decode/encode VARINT:

```py
def to_varint(src):
    buf = b""
    while True:
        towrite = src & 0x7f
        src >>= 7
        if src:
            buf += bytes((towrite | 0x80,))
        else:
            buf += bytes((towrite,))
            break
    return buf

def from_varint(src):
    shift = 0
    result = 0
    for i in src:
        result |= (i & 0x7f) << shift
        shift += 7
    return result
```

So using this function we can decode your values:

```py
from datetime import datetime

...

values = """\
bf aa b8 c3 e5 2f
d7 be ba c3 e5 2f
80 a0 c0 c3 e5 2f
a7 fc bf c3 e5 2f
ae fd f2 c3 e5 2f
9e dd fa c3 e5 2f
c7 ce fa c3 e5 2f
b9 f5 82 c4 e5 2f
f8 95 f2 c3 e5 2f"""

for value in values.splitlines():
    timestamp = from_varint(bytes.fromhex(value))
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp / 1000)
    print(dt)
```

To get current timestamp in this encoding you can use next code:

```py
current = to_varint(int(datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000)).hex(" ")
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much! I wouldn't think of it.